# app/console sulu:security:user:create is working but sulu-login doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, sulu

I am new in administrating websites with Symfony and Sulu CMS.

But now I have to setup an test environment based on an existing project. So far I think I've managed to get Symfony and Sulu basically working.

Now to my problem:
I created an user with `php app/console sulu:security:user:create` and this was working fine. I have not been able to create a role so far, but there are existing roles in the MySQL database, so I used one of them for my new user.
When I try to login on the sulu.lo/admin page the new combination of user and password isn't working.

Are there any checks I can perform to got a hint what the problem could be?

Please ask me for needed extra information.

Best regards

Comment: What roles have already been existing? Which one did you use?

Comment: I used the role "user" in system "Sulu"

Comment: Did you also use the `php app/console sulu:build dev` command? It creates a user using the same commands, which should be working. Can you login with the credentials admin/admin?

Comment: Yes i used this command. But it throws the same exception. Also `sulu:build:dev` cannot create a role and further no user. I am getting an ORM\ORMInvalidArgumentException with following text:

A new entity was found through the relationship 'App\Bundle\SecurityBundle\Entity\Role#permissions' 
that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity: 
Sulu\Bundle\SecurityBundle\Entity\Permission@<someHash>. To solve this issue: 
Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on this unknown entity or configure cascade persist this association in the mapping 
for example ...

Comment: I tried to adapt the relationship settings within the *.orm.xml file to `on-delete='CASCADE'` and, if there is an own `cascade`-node available to `<cascade><cascade-remove/></cascade>` but there is still the same behaviour.

Comment: In the meanwhile i got the console command working without throwing an execption. I corrected the mappings by adding the inversed-by=... parameters within the *.orm.xml files and using cascade-all. Nevertheless, login with new created user doesn't work.

Comment: What exactly did you do? Can you past the changes somewhere? What database and Sulu version are you using? What response did you get? It's very hard to answer to that, since I can't reproduce it.

Answer (score 7):

1. Create user role

   `$ php ./bin/adminconsole sulu:security:role:create --env=prod`

Input your role name and choose system. The output will be something like this:

```
Please choose a rolename: admin
Please choose a system: 
 [0] Sulu
 > 0
Created role "admin" in system "Sulu".
```

2. Create user:

   `$ php ./bin/adminconsole sulu:security:user:create --env=prod`

Input you values. For example:

```
Please choose a username: manager
Please choose a FirstName: Ural
Please choose a LastName: Davletshin
Please choose a Email: mail@dot.com
Please choose a locale
  [0] de
  [1] en
  [2] fr
  [3] nl
  > 1 
    Please choose a role: 
     [0] admin
     > 0
   Please choose a Password: 
   Created user "manager" in role "admin"
```

3. Go to admin login page type your username and password and welcome :-)